# Recursive nesting with parameter

Tags: recursion, iteration

I would like to apply a function `f` recursively to an expression `expr` an arbitrary number of times. However the catch is that `f` also takes a parameter `i` and I want it to change with each application. So applied once should look like `f[1][expr]`.

Concretely what I want, should look like this:

```
f[5][
   f[4][
      f[3][
         f[2][
            f[1][expr] ]]]]
```

It seems to me this should be easy somehow, but I don't know how to leverage functions like `Nest`, `Do` or `Fold` in such a way that they produce this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html)

```
Fold[f[#2][#] &, expr, Range[5]]
```

> f[5][f[4][f[3][f[2][f[1][expr]]]]]

```
Fold[#2 @ # &, expr, f/@ Range[5]]
```

> f[5][f[4][f[3][f[2][f[1][expr]]]]]

#### [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html)

```
Module[{i = 1}, Nest[f[i++]@# &, expr, 5]]
```

> f[5][f[4][f[3][f[2][f[1][expr]]]]]

#### [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)

```
Composition[## & @@ (f /@ Reverse[Range@5])]@ expr
```

> f[5][f[4][f[3][f[2][f[1][expr]]]]]

```
(Composition @@ f /@ Reverse[Range@5]) @ expr
```

> f[5][f[4][f[3][f[2][f[1][expr]]]]]

#### [`Compose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compose.html)

```
Compose[## & @@ (f /@ Reverse[Range@5]), expr]
```

> f[5][f[4][f[3][f[2][f[1][expr]]]]]